# HTTPS - Cookie "HttpOnly" and "secure "

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

My website is running under HTTPS protocol and I use only 1 cookie (PHPSESSID). My server is Apache 2.2.22. I noticed that my cookie doesn't have the "HttpOnly" and "Secure" headers, then I tried to set it via my .htaccess :

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
```

By the way, the .htaccess works perfectly (url rewriting, deflate, expire headers, Etags etc...). But now... my website generates 4 cookies and PHPSESSID seems not to be secure :

[image]

Am i missing something ?

Comment: .htaccess is the wrong way to go about this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php, http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Thanks. I removed the line in .htaccess and added ini_set("session.cookie_secure", '1') on top of page. Works perfect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess is the wrong way to go about this.

PHP has session configuration options for this, you can either set them in your PHP configuration in the usual way (php.ini, ini_set, …), or via a dedicated function call.

`session.cookie_httponly` and `session.cookie_secure` are the relevant options here.

See http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php for additional details.